# Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366) - Angular

Tags: angular

I need help with this error, I don't know how to correct or fix it

[image]

Comment: What does it return when the `if` isn't hit?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all paths are returning a string. Or you need to declare the type of your function as `string | void` or you need to add `return '';` at the end of your function. Should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

**You got this error because you miss the else condition.**

```
if(respuesta === this.opcionSeleccionada){
    return 'active text-light';
}else{
    //Here you need to return something.
}
```